# MS Access While Loop Skips first record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a split multi-user MS Access (2013 ACCDE file) database that is used to email out class schedules and syllabi to professors.  The end user presses a button on a form when they are ready to send emails and then the DB has code that cycles through each entry (about 70) in a filtered datasheet within a subform. Generally, the code to add attachments and to send email works... However, with how the code is set below, the last person on the email list gets emailed twice... they are both the first and the last person the DB sends an email to...

I've included my pertinent code below.  As always I'm greatly appreciative of any assistance you can offer.

```
Private Sub SchedEmailButton_Click()

    Me.FacEmailingList2.SetFocus
    RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast  'I've tried moving this and the next line of code to the "Sub Form_Current" (See below) but then the application just blinks and does nothing
    RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst
```

Alternatively, I've tried this as well for the button, which is when only the first record gets skipped (Thus my post title):

```
Private Sub SchedEmailButton_Click()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Me.FacEmailingList2.SetFocus 
        While Not rst.EOF
        rst.MoveNext
        Wend
        Set rst = Nothing
```

This is the code that loops through the list of email recipients, stripped down (edited) to really what matters due to its length:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

[Set Variables]

        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast  'This causes the email automation code to fail
        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst
        While Me.CurrentRecord <= Me.Recordset.RecordCount
[Working Loop Code Area]
        Wend
```

[EDIT]This is the full code (just in case):

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFiltered As DAO.Recordset
Dim WhereSem As String
Dim WhereYear As String
Dim WhereFac As String
Dim WSemq As String
Dim WYearq As String
Dim WFacq As String
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim objOutlookRecip As Object
Dim objOutlookAttach As Object
Dim docuser As String
Dim docpath1 As String
Dim docpath2 As String
Dim docname As String
Dim docaddpath As String
Dim fulldoc As String
Dim syllabifile As String
Dim syllabidoc As String
Dim syllabidocx As String
Dim syllabipdf As String
Dim syllabiloc As String
Dim ABETfile As String
Dim ABETOf As String
Dim ABETOdoc As String
Dim ABETOdocx As String
Dim ABETOpdf As String
Dim ABETOloc As String
Dim ABETQf As String
Dim ABETQdoc As String
Dim ABETQdocx As String
Dim ABETQpdf As String
Dim ABETQtemp As String
Dim ABETQinst As String
Dim ABETQloc As String
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim abatt As Integer

abatt = 0       

        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast  'This causes the email automation code to fail
        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst
        While Me.CurrentRecord <= Me.Recordset.RecordCount

            WhereSem = "[Semester_ID]= " & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![Semester])
            WhereYear = "[Year_ID]= " & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![YearSelect])
            WhereFac = "[Fac_ID]= " & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![FacEmailID])

            'Close report in case it's open
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "ScheduleEmail", acSaveYes 

            'Open report
            DoCmd.OpenReport "ScheduleEmail", acViewReport, , WhereSem & " And " & WhereYear & " And " & WhereFac 

            docuser = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
            docaddpath = Left(Reports!ScheduleEmail![Semester], 2) & Reports!ScheduleEmail![SemesterYear] & "\"
            docpath1 = docuser & "\documents\DB\Docs\"
            docpath2 = docpath1 & docaddpath
            docname = Reports!ScheduleEmail![Emp_Last] & Reports!ScheduleEmail![Emp_First]
            fulldoc = docpath2 & docname & ".pdf"

            If Dir(docpath1, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                MkDir (docpath1)
            End If

            If Dir(docpath2, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                MkDir (docpath2)
            End If

            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, fulldoc, False

            ' Create the Outlook session.
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

            ' Create the message.
            Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


            With objOutlookMsg
                ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
                .To = Me.Email

                ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
                .Subject = Me.emailsubject
                .Body = Me.EmailText

                ' Add attachments to the message.
                If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
                    .Attachments.Add (fulldoc)

                    'Send the Syllabi for the class
                    Set db = CurrentDb()

                    WSemq = "Semester_ID =" & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![Semester])

                    WYearq = "Year_ID =" & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![YearSelect])

                    WFacq = "Fac_ID =" & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![FacEmailID])

                    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM RE_SchedCourse_EmailAttachment2_Q WHERE " & WSemq & " And " & WYearq & " And " & WFacq, dbOpenDynaset)

                    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                        rs.MoveLast
                        rs.MoveFirst
                    End If

                    Do While Not rs.EOF

                        If IsNull(rs!Fac_ID) Then
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                        syllabifile = rs!Prefix & rs!Prefix_Num & " Syllabus"
                        syllabiloc = "S:\Latest Syllabi\"
                        syllabidoc = syllabifile & ".doc"
                        syllabidocx = syllabifile & ".docx"
                        syllabipdf = syllabifile & ".pdf"

                        If FileExists(syllabiloc & syllabidoc) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (syllabiloc & syllabidoc)
                        ElseIf FileExists(syllabiloc & syllabidocx) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (syllabiloc & syllabidocx)
                        ElseIf FileExists(syllabiloc & syllabipdf) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (syllabiloc & syllabipdf)
                        End If

                        'Set the ABETfile names
                        ABETfile = rs!Prefix & " " & rs!Prefix_Num    '& " " & rs!Course_Name

                        'Set the ABET Outcomes files
                        ABETOf = ABETfile & " ABET Outcomes"
                        ABETOloc = "S:\ABET Outcomes\"
                        ABETOdoc = ABETOf & ".doc"
                        ABETOdocx = ABETOf & ".docx"
                        ABETOpdf = ABETOf & ".pdf"

                        'If there are ABET Outcomes send those
                        If FileExists(ABETOloc & ABETOdoc) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETOloc & ABETOdoc)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETOloc & ABETOdocx) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETOloc & ABETOdocx)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETOloc & ABETOpdf) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETOloc & ABETOpdf)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        End If

                        'Set the ABET Quizzes files
                        ABETQf = ABETfile & " ABET Quizzes"
                        ABETQloc = "S:\ABET Quizzes\"
                        ABETQtemp = "ABET Data Fall TEMPLATE.xlsx"
                        ABETQinst = "ABET TESTS (instructions).docx"
                        ABETQdoc = ABETQf & ".doc"
                        ABETQdocx = ABETQf & ".docx"
                        ABETQpdf = ABETQf & ".pdf"

                        'If there are ABET Quizzes send those
                        If FileExists(ABETQloc & ABETQdoc) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETQloc & ABETQdoc)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETQloc & ABETQdocx) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETQloc & ABETQdocx)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETQloc & ABETQpdf) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETQloc & ABETQpdf)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        End If

                        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                            rs.MoveNext
                        End If
                    Loop

                    'Attach extra ABET Quiz documents
                    If abatt >= 1 Then
                        Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(ABETQloc & ABETQtemp)
                        Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(ABETQloc & ABETQinst)
                        abatt = 0
                    End If

                    rs.Close

                    Set rs = Nothing

                End If

                ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
                For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
                    objOutlookRecip.Resolve
                Next

                ' Should we display the message before sending?
                If DisplayMsg Then
                    .Display
                Else
                    .Save
                    .Send
                End If
            End With

            Set objOutlook = Nothing

            DoCmd.Close acReport, "ScheduleEmail", acSaveYes

            If Me.CurrentRecord <= Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then

                DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNext
            Else: DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acFirst
            End If
        Wend
```

[EDIT]

Here's what the button code looks like now.  Because I'm referencing a subform everything seems to be messed up with how the references are made:

```
Private Sub SchedEmailButton_Click()

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = Me.FacEmailingList2.Form.Recordset

Me.FacEmailingList2.SetFocus
RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst

While Not rst.EOF 'CurentRecord <= RecordCount

    SchedEmail
    'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNext
    DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNext

    If rst.EOF Then 'CurrentRecord <= Recordset.RecordCount Then

        DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNext
    Else: DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acFirst
    End If
Wend
```

Here's the basic changes I've made to the email loop (I've made it it's own procedure, this is more for reference than anything):

```
Sub SchedEmail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFiltered As DAO.Recordset
Dim WhereSem As String
Dim WhereYear As String
Dim WhereFac As String
Dim WSemq As String
Dim WYearq As String
Dim WFacq As String
Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim objOutlookRecip As Object
Dim objOutlookAttach As Object
Dim docuser As String
Dim docpath1 As String
Dim docpath2 As String
Dim docname As String
Dim docaddpath As String
Dim fulldoc As String
Dim syllabifile As String
Dim syllabidoc As String
Dim syllabidocx As String
Dim syllabipdf As String
Dim syllabiloc As String
Dim ABETfile As String
Dim ABETOf As String
Dim ABETOdoc As String
Dim ABETOdocx As String
Dim ABETOpdf As String
Dim ABETOloc As String
Dim ABETQf As String
Dim ABETQdoc As String
Dim ABETQdocx As String
Dim ABETQpdf As String
Dim ABETQtemp As String
Dim ABETQinst As String
Dim ABETQloc As String
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim abatt As Integer

abatt = 0       

        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast  'This causes the email automation code to fail
        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst
        While Me.CurrentRecord <= Me.Recordset.RecordCount

            WhereSem = "[Semester_ID]= " & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![Semester])
            WhereYear = "[Year_ID]= " & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![YearSelect])
            WhereFac = "[Fac_ID]= " & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![FacEmailID])

            'Close report in case it's open
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "ScheduleEmail", acSaveYes 

            'Open report
            DoCmd.OpenReport "ScheduleEmail", acViewReport, , WhereSem & " And " & WhereYear & " And " & WhereFac 

            docuser = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
            docaddpath = Left(Reports!ScheduleEmail![Semester], 2) & Reports!ScheduleEmail![SemesterYear] & "\"
            docpath1 = docuser & "\documents\DB\Docs\"
            docpath2 = docpath1 & docaddpath
            docname = Reports!ScheduleEmail![Emp_Last] & Reports!ScheduleEmail![Emp_First]
            fulldoc = docpath2 & docname & ".pdf"

            If Dir(docpath1, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                MkDir (docpath1)
            End If

            If Dir(docpath2, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                MkDir (docpath2)
            End If

            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, fulldoc, False

            ' Create the Outlook session.
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

            ' Create the message.
            Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)


            With objOutlookMsg
                ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
                .To = Me.Email

                ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
                .Subject = Me.emailsubject
                .Body = Me.EmailText

                ' Add attachments to the message.
                If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
                    .Attachments.Add (fulldoc)

                    'Send the Syllabi for the class
                    Set db = CurrentDb()

                    WSemq = "Semester_ID =" & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![Semester])

                    WYearq = "Year_ID =" & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![YearSelect])

                    WFacq = "Fac_ID =" & CLng(Forms![MenMain3]![NavigationSubform].Form![FacEmailID])

                    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM RE_SchedCourse_EmailAttachment2_Q WHERE " & WSemq & " And " & WYearq & " And " & WFacq, dbOpenDynaset)

                    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                        rs.MoveLast
                        rs.MoveFirst
                    End If

                    Do While Not rs.EOF

                        If IsNull(rs!Fac_ID) Then
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                        syllabifile = rs!Prefix & rs!Prefix_Num & " Syllabus"
                        syllabiloc = "S:\Latest Syllabi\"
                        syllabidoc = syllabifile & ".doc"
                        syllabidocx = syllabifile & ".docx"
                        syllabipdf = syllabifile & ".pdf"

                        If FileExists(syllabiloc & syllabidoc) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (syllabiloc & syllabidoc)
                        ElseIf FileExists(syllabiloc & syllabidocx) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (syllabiloc & syllabidocx)
                        ElseIf FileExists(syllabiloc & syllabipdf) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (syllabiloc & syllabipdf)
                        End If

                        'Set the ABETfile names
                        ABETfile = rs!Prefix & " " & rs!Prefix_Num    '& " " & rs!Course_Name

                        'Set the ABET Outcomes files
                        ABETOf = ABETfile & " ABET Outcomes"
                        ABETOloc = "S:\ABET Outcomes\"
                        ABETOdoc = ABETOf & ".doc"
                        ABETOdocx = ABETOf & ".docx"
                        ABETOpdf = ABETOf & ".pdf"

                        'If there are ABET Outcomes send those
                        If FileExists(ABETOloc & ABETOdoc) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETOloc & ABETOdoc)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETOloc & ABETOdocx) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETOloc & ABETOdocx)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETOloc & ABETOpdf) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETOloc & ABETOpdf)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        End If

                        'Set the ABET Quizzes files
                        ABETQf = ABETfile & " ABET Quizzes"
                        ABETQloc = "S:\ABET Quizzes\"
                        ABETQtemp = "ABET Data Fall TEMPLATE.xlsx"
                        ABETQinst = "ABET TESTS (instructions).docx"
                        ABETQdoc = ABETQf & ".doc"
                        ABETQdocx = ABETQf & ".docx"
                        ABETQpdf = ABETQf & ".pdf"

                        'If there are ABET Quizzes send those
                        If FileExists(ABETQloc & ABETQdoc) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETQloc & ABETQdoc)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETQloc & ABETQdocx) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETQloc & ABETQdocx)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        ElseIf FileExists(ABETQloc & ABETQpdf) Then
                            .Attachments.Add (ABETQloc & ABETQpdf)
                            abatt = abatt + 1
                        End If

                        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                            rs.MoveNext
                        End If
                    Loop

                    'Attach extra ABET Quiz documents
                    If abatt >= 1 Then
                        Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(ABETQloc & ABETQtemp)
                        Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(ABETQloc & ABETQinst)
                        abatt = 0
                    End If

                    rs.Close

                    Set rs = Nothing

                End If

                ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
                For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
                    objOutlookRecip.Resolve
                Next

                ' Should we display the message before sending?
                If DisplayMsg Then
                    .Display
                Else
                    .Save
                    .Send
                End If
            End With

            Set objOutlook = Nothing

            DoCmd.Close acReport, "ScheduleEmail", acSaveYes

            If Me.CurrentRecord <= Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then

                DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNext
            Else: DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acFirst
            End If
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to dig through.  Can you reduce the problem to just a few lines to post here as a sample?  If you do, then there is a good chance you might see your problem.

Comment: I was afraid of that (the whole too much code to dig through thing...)  I erred on the side of too much information here. For this issue the bottom loop code is there for general reference only.  The main loop runs fine, it just doesn't start correctly...  I'll cut out extraneous code

Comment: I'm looking at your loop, and it looks like all it does is call `MoveNext` over and over again. The placement of the rest of the code might be significant. If `rst` starts on the first record and `MoveNext` is the first thing that happens inside the loop, then this would skip over the first result before it got processed; `MoveNext` should go at the end of the loop instead of the beginning. I'm not sure where `rst` starts, since I don't work with VBA on any kind of regular basis, but that would be a pretty common mistake, I imagine. Something along those lines seems like the most likely cause.

Comment: I really don't thing using the 'Current' event is the best place to place your code to send emails. My suggestion is to use the 'SchedEmailButton_Click' and do all the work either inside that subroutine, or if you want, you could make your code a Function and call it. The biggest change I suggest is to use a 'recordset clone', thus you would process just like a normal recordset (i.e. Set RS = ...; Do While Not RS.EOF; your code; RS.MoveNext; Loop;  If you wanted to test, don't insert your code yet, just display the recordcount, then count / Debug.Print as you loop thru.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone.  Wayne - I've moved the code out of the 'Current' event and made it part of the "On Click" event with the button "SchedEmailButton".  My problem now (I think) is getting the correct references to move to the next record.  I can get multiple emails to send... but only for the first record now.  I'll post the changes so you can see what I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work!

Wayne's suggestion of moving the code from the sub form "Current" event to the buttons "Click" event was  very helpful and got me on the right path.

I had a bit of an issue with how to get the loop to go to the next record, but this is what I ended up with after searching a bit more:

```
Private Sub SchedEmailButton_Click()

Dim rst As Object 'DAO.Recordset    <-- For some reason unknown to me the code didn't like declaring as a "DAO.Recordset"

Set rst = Me.FacEmailingList2.Form.Recordset

With rst
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                SchedEmail
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
        Set rst = Nothing
```

These didn't work to move to the next record (I don't know why):

```
RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNext
DoCmd.GoToRecord record:=acNext
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
```

Comment: First, I think you should use either "Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone" or "Set rst = Me.FacEmailingList2.Form.RecordsetClone".  Second, unless there is no alternative, it is always best to type objects explicitly (sometimes you can get some weird results by using just 'Object'). Thus I suggest: "Dim rst As DAO.Recordset"

Comment: Wayne,  I went back and retried the changes you suggested.  I was able to set the object type to "DAO.Recordset" with no problem... However, when I tried to change from "Me.FacEmailingList2.Form.Recordset" to "Me.FacEmailingList2.Form.RecordsetClone" the loop went back to being stuck on the first record while emailing.

Comment: Yikes! Did you do anything about subroutine 'SchedEmail'? In there you are moving around in your recordset(s).  You should have only ONE place that is using the recordset.

Comment: Wayne, apologies for the delayed response... First, I'm a little unclear as to the importance of using the clone over the actual recordset (other than the clone is read only).  I'm also unsure as to why the recordset(s) in the "SchedEmail" routine would effect the behavior of the clone. It doesn't refer to that recordset at all.  I'm still learning here... so understanding this would be good for me in the future.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: My concern is the possibility of introducing a problem - depending on what your code currently looks like. Long ago, you had 'Sub Form_Current' that contained a lot of activity for that event.. i.e. what happens if a user just clicked on a row? that would fire the event and run all that code - assuming it is still there - maybe you moved it to sub 'SchedEmail'. The second issue is the confusion factor because your 'SchedEmailButton_Click' moves through your recordset, but also calls 'SchedEmail' which also spins through the recordset. I fail to understand that & believe that can be an issue.

Comment: I can see your concern... I changed the SchedEmail code so that the code at the top (and the associated While loop end) is no longer present:  ***'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast  'This causes the email automation code to fail
        'RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToFirst
        While Me.CurrentRecord <= Me.Recordset.RecordCount' ***  Now the code has no reference to the record set referenced in the SchedEmailButton_Click. Also, there is no more code in the "Sub Form_Current" to refer to.